# How to check if and only if one of the conditions are true in a set of statements in Julia?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have the following statements:

```
1 == 1
2 == 1
3 == 2
```

I want to verify *if and only if* one of those statements is `true`. The expected result for the above example is a `true`. Obviously, if I use the `all` function for the example above, I get `false`. If I use the `any` function, then it breaks the rule in other situations. For example:

```
julia> any([1==1, 2==2, 3==1])
true
```

I need `false` in this case because there are two `true` statements rather than one. Another approach is using many chained truthy statements like `||` and `&&`, which leads to many lines of code if my statements are more in the count. So, I'm looking for a good and optimal way for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach can be utilizing the `sum` function :

```
julia> sum([1==1, 2==2, 3==1])
2

julia> sum([1==1, 2==1, 3==1])
1
```

So:

- If the result is a `0`, Then all are `false` statements.
- If the result is `1`, there is only a `true` statement.
- Finally, in other cases, there is more than one true statement.

If I try to benchmark my proposal against the @fredrikekre's:

```
julia> f1(vec::Vector{Bool}) = sum(vec) == 1;

julia> f2(vec::Vector{Bool}) = count(vec) == 1;

julia> @benchmark f1([1==1, 2==1, 3==1])
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 993 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  37.059 ns …  1.709 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 97.14%
 Time  (median):     39.174 ns              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   44.735 ns ± 55.112 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.33% ±  3.47%

  ▄▆█▆▅▃▂▂▁    ▁▁▁▁              ▁▂▂▃                         ▂
  █████████▇▆▇██████▇▆▆▇▆▆▇▇██▇███████▇▇▇▇▆▆▅▇▆▇▆▆▆▅▅▁▆▅▅▄▄▅▅ █
  37.1 ns      Histogram: log(frequency) by time      86.8 ns <

 Memory estimate: 64 bytes, allocs estimate: 1.

julia> @benchmark f2([1==1, 2==1, 3==1])
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 992 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  37.399 ns …  2.559 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 97.92%
 Time  (median):     39.516 ns              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   50.292 ns ± 68.392 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.74% ±  3.50%

  ▄█▆▄▃▁▁                    ▁▁▃▄▄▄                           ▁
  ███████▇▅▆▇████▇▆▇▆▆▅▆▆▆▆▅▇█████████▆▄▆▆▇▇▇▆▆▅▆▆▆▅▄▄▅▆▆▅▅▅▃ █
  37.4 ns      Histogram: log(frequency) by time      95.6 ns <

 Memory estimate: 64 bytes, allocs estimate: 1.
```

I can see mine performs slightly better.

Comment: You could make that a small one line function: `one_true(list) = sum(list) == 1 ? true : false`

Comment: @NilsL. the `? true ...` part is unnecessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`count`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.count):

```
julia> count(i == 2 for i in 1:4) == 1
true

julia> count([1 == 2, 2 == 2, 3 == 2]) == 1
true
```

Comment: Yes, this is another approach. Thanks!